# How can I convert byte to fixed size (size = 8) bitArray

Tags: c#, byte, bit, bitarray

I want Convert Byte to fixed size (size = 8) bit array

Want Behavior:

```
var bits = GetBits(0x00); // returned [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

bits = GetBits(0x01); // returned [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

bits = GetBits(0x0A); // returned [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

I used below code but it didn't return what I want.

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(byte);
```

Comment: `BitArray`' constructor takes a length not a byte to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong constructor.

Try this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 12 });
```

[image: BitArray]

The constructor you're using is saying how long you want the bit array to be.